# PHPMailer how to pass variable

Tags: php, parameter-passing, phpmailer

I have seen people using `$mail->get_include_contents()` but I don't know exactly how it works.

I want to active an account via email. I've got a template php, html or tpl, which I want to pass the username, a random key, email, etc. Consider that I'm using Smarty in all my project.

On my gmail.php I've got:

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/MailActivation.php'), $variables);
```

Could somebody explain to me how I could do it?

Answer (score 5):

¡Finally!

This was the result:

```
    <?php

    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    require_once (dirname(__FILE__).'/../../controller/SignUpController.php');

    $variables = [$username, $email, $randomkey];

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();

    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    // use
    // $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = "your_email";

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = "your_password_email";

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom('user_email_from', 'title_to_display');

    //Set an alternative reply-to address: it's optional
    //$mail->addReplyTo('user_email_reply', 'user_email_name');

    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress($email, $firstname . " " . $lastname);

    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject';

// Settin variables    
    $message = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/MailActivation.html');
    $message = str_replace('%testusername%', $username, $message);
    $message = str_replace('%testemail%', $email, $message);
    $message = str_replace('%testrandomkey%', $randomkey, $message);

    $mail->msgHTML($message);

    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

    //Attach an image file
    //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

// For sending an image inline
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage(dirname(__FILE__).'/images/frontimage.jpg', 'front', 'images/frontimage.jpg');

    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {


           echo "Message sent!";
        }
?>
```

In my ActivationTemplate.html I just create an html file and where i wanted to insert the variables i just put:

```
Lorem ipsum %testusername% dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nulla elit, mattis non leo in, ornare interdum ante. Proin eget velit purus. Sed convallis lectus sed libero ornare, sit amet pharetra nisi facilisis. Cras fermentum nulla quis purus egestas, in accumsan nisl dictum. Donec in nisi vel enim pretium posuere at nec ante. Mauris tempus velit vel urna commodo accumsan. %testemail%
```

I think it doesn't matter if you use a php template or html.

Answer (score 0):

Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error.

```
 $mail->Body = get_include_contents('sample.php', $variable);
```

**sample.php**

```
<table width='600px' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeee'><img src='logo.png' /></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#ffffff'  bordercolor='#eeeeee'>
<div style='border:1px solid #eeeeee;font-family:Segoe  UI,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;padding:20px 10px;'>
<p>Variable one is <?php echo $one; ?>.</p>
 <p>Variable two is <?php echo $two; ?>.</p>
<p>Thanks</p>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```